# Im having an authorization problem when trying to clone a pipeline in azure devops

Tags: azure, api, azure-devops, authorization, azure-pipelines

I have the correct authorizations and i can clone the pipeline manually but when i try to do it with postman i receive the following response:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "You are not authorized to access this API. Please contact your project administrator",
    "typeName": "System.UnauthorizedAccessException, mscorlib",
    "typeKey": "UnauthorizedAccessException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 0
}
```

I am using the following url:GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/test/cloneoperation/{cloneOperationId}?api-version=5.0-preview.2

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _apis/test/cloneoperation/xxx is not used to clone pipeline, it is used to get clone information for test plan/suite.

To clone pipeline, you could [get a build definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0), then update something and [create a new build definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0).